# Unable to grow curry leaf plant successfully, what could I be doing wrong?

Tags: diagnosis

Some background - As you can see in the picture below, my plant has plenty of those fruits now. After watching a Youtube video about 3 weeks back, I pluck few of these that were black and seems ready (easily pluck-able) and left it in a cup in shade for about a week. Its been sown in a container for about 2 weeks now (1 inch deep in the soil) but nothing has grown yet 
I am using the Kellogg Patio Plus gardening soil, watering twice a week and the container is in shade.

My first try - Last year, 2019 in Fall also I had tried sowing but no luck. From a Youtube video I watched that time, I remember the person saying these seeds usually have 90% germination rate..
I live in Fremont, is there anything I might be doing wrong? Any suggestions/tips are welcome.

[image]

Comment: Did you plant the whole fruits, or did you remove the seeds from the fruit?

Comment: @csk, I planted the whole fruit this time. Last year I had planted only the seed.

Answer (score 0):

Most sources say you will get better germination rates by planting cleaned seeds than by planting the whole fruit. [This source](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/start-murraya-koenigii-berries-92705.html) has detailed for preparing and planting the seeds.

Compared to their instructions, one obvious thing you did differently was how deep you planted the seeds in the soil. You planted 1 inch deep; that guide says to plant the seed "at a depth equal to its diameter" or about 1/3 inch.

The same guide also says to allow *at least* 6-8 weeks for germination, but that it might even take several months. So your seeds wouldn't be sprouting yet anyway.

I would suggest you clear a bit of dirt from above your planted fruits, so the fruits are only about 1/3 inch underground. Then have patience and continue watering them for at least 4 more weeks, but maybe as long as 2-3 months.

If you're willing to risk killing one, you could dig up a fruit to see how much of the fruit is left. If there's a lot of fruit left around the seed, try cleaning off the seed and replanting it. If the seed looks completely intact and healthy but without any sprout emerging, you might try doing the same to a few more fruits. If it's starting to sprout, leave the other ones alone so you don't damage them.